# Retrieving Javascript value from Page 1 to Page 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm facing a problem where my AJAX function needs to send a value from page 1 and in page 2 where the function catches and store it.

Here's my page one AJAX function :

```
top.location.href = 'http://www.something.com/redirect.php?email=' + $('#email').val();
```

So the value of the email is "$('email').val();

Here in my second page, I'm using this AJAX function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#iframe").load(function(event){
var email = $('#email').val();
$('#frame1').contents().find('#iddatabase').val(email);
$('#frame1').contents().find('#fgr').submit();
redirect();
});
```

The problem is the AJAX value in the second page is missing and i need help on fixing it.

Comment: So far, you're not doing anything related to AJAX, you're just passing a querystring value along on your URL. Researching on how to retrieve a querystring value via JavaScript will help you quite a bit.

Comment: @Chris , I just got the result . Thank you mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer thanks to some help of Chris,

I just added these javascript line :

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Then I change my

```
var email = $('#email').val();
```

to

```
var email = getParameterByName('email');
```